# Groovy String concatenation with null checks

Tags: string, groovy, null, concatenation

Is there a better way to do this?  Note: `part1`, `part2` and `part3` are string variables defined elsewhere (they can be null).

```
def list = [part1, part2, part3]
list.removeAll([null])
def ans = list.join()
```

The desired result is a concatenated string with null values left out.

Comment: You can pack it all in to one line: `def ans = [part1, part2, part3].removeAll([null]).join()`, but I'm not sure that's quite what you mean by "better".

Comment: @cdeszaq That might be better, but it does not work. The removeAll() method returns a Boolean, and join() cannot be called on a Boolean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def ans = [part1, part2, part3].findAll({it != null}).join()
```

You *might* be able to shrink the closure down to just `{it}` depending on how your list items will evaluate according to [Groovy Truth](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth), but this should make it a bit tighter.

Note: The [GDK javadocs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) are a *great* resource.

Comment: Can also do `.findAll({it?.trim()})` to exclude both null and empty strings.

Answer (score 10):

If you use [`findAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28%29) with no parameters. It will return every "truthful" value, so this should work:

```
def ans = [part1, part2, part3].findAll().join()
```

Notice that `findAll` will filter out empty strings (because they are evaluated as false in a boolean context), but that doesn't matter in this case, as the empty strings don't add anything to `join()` :)

If this is a simplified question and you want to keep empty string values, you can use [`findResults`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findResults%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)`{ it }`.

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer with the addition of confirming how `findAll` works, right?

Comment: It also removes the closure passed to `findAll` and mentions `findResults`, which might be useful for other cases.

Comment: Good point. `findResults` has the nice ability to transform things as it filters. +1

Comment: I do like this, but it fails for me.  I am using Groovy 1.7.10, and the findAll() method throws an error when one of the array elements is null.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, the docs says the niladic `findAll` was added in Groovy 1.8.1

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do this as a fold operation with `inject`:

```
def ans = [part1, part2, part3].inject('') { result, element -> 
    result + (element ?: '')
}
```

This iterates the whole list and concatenates each successive element to a result, with logic to use the empty string for null elements.

Comment: +1 Inject is a much more powerful way than my answer. It _might_ be a bit more complex and harder to understand though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep`:

```
groovy:000> list = ['a', 'b', null, 'c']
===> [a, b, null, c]
groovy:000> list.grep {it != null}.join()
===> abc
```

Comment: You could also just use `.grep()` since it defaults to using Groovy Truth as it's filter, but this is the same as using `findAll()`.