# Calling Java Apache StringUtils.join() from Groovy

Tags: java, string, groovy, apache-stringutils, string-utils

I am attempting to call the Apache Commons StringUtils.join() method from within a Groovy class.  I want to concatenate 3 strings (`part1`, `part2`, and `part3`).

Why doesn't this work?

```
def path = StringUtils.join([part1, part2, part3]) //1
```

But the following line works:

```
def path = StringUtils.join([part1, part2, part3] as String[]) //2
```

A follow up question.  Why does this work?  I am using StringUtils v 2.6, so it does not have a varargs method. Does groovy always convert method parameters to an array?

```
def path = StringUtils.join(part1, part2, part3)  //3
```

This is largely a curiosity question.  I am not going to use StringUtils because I posted a [separate question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775951/groovy-string-concatenation-with-null-checks) and found a better solution. However, I would still like to understand why technique #1 does not work, yet #3 does work.

Comment: For #1, the result is a String representation of the array, not the actual elements of the array concatenated together.  It appear the array is converted to a String before it is sent to the join() method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, to show what is happening, let's write a script and show what output we get:

```
@Grab( 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' )
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

def (part1,part2,part3) = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

def path = StringUtils.join( [ part1, part2, part3 ] )
println "1) $path"

path = StringUtils.join( [ part1, part2, part3 ] as String[] )
println "2) $path"

path = StringUtils.join( part1, part2, part3 )
println "3) $path"
```

This prints:

```
1) [one, two, three]
2) onetwothree
3) onetwothree
```

Basically, the only one of your method calls that matches a signature in the StringUtils class is `2)`, as it matches the `Object[]` [method definition](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).  For the other two, Groovy is picking the best match that is can find for your method call.

For both `1)` and `3)`, it's doing the same thing.  Wrapping the parameters as an `Object[]` and calling the same method as `2)`

For `3)` this is fine, as you get an `Object[]` with 3 elements, but for `1)`, you get an `Object[]` with one element; your `List`.

A way of getting it to work with the List parameter, would be to use the [spread operator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html) like so:

```
path = StringUtils.join( *[ part1, part2, part3 ] )
println "4) $path"
```

Which would then print:

```
4) onetwothree
```

As expected (it would put all the elements of the list in as separate parameters, and these would then be put into an `Object[]` with three elements as in example `3)`

Comment: This answer is phenomenal. I wish I could provide multiple upvotes.  The description is clean and thorough.  Plus, you mentioned the spread operator.  Thanks tim_yates.